# how to implement Modbus RTU Master in Digi Module Connect me 9210

Tags: c, embedded, modbus

I am trying to implement Modbus RTU Master in Digi Module connect me 9210 device. For this purpose I am using libmodbus library.

What would be device name I have to give in NetOs to connect with my local Computer.?

Now I am using

```
ctx = modbus_new_rtu("COM3", 19200, 'N', 8, 1);
modbus_set_slave(ctx, SERVER_ID);

/* TCP */
//  ctx = modbus_new_tcp("10.0.0.66", 502);

modbus_set_debug(ctx, TRUE);

if (modbus_connect(ctx) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n",
                modbus_strerror(errno));
    modbus_free(ctx);
    return -1;
}
```

But its keep saying connection failed. I have also tried "/dev/USB0" and "/dev/ttyS0". I have Modbus Slave in my local computer to test with the Module client.

Comment: Try with another tty, like `ttyS3`, if installed. Surely cannot work with posted code `"COM3"` od `USB0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my Errors . There was an API Issue in the Digi Module while opening the default port "/com/0".

Also had to change the libmodbus library little bit to work with Digi because it was using the flags not supported by the device.